Brand new user not shown as new contributor
A brand new user posted a question on Server Fault today. 
The question was migrated to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.
The user is brand new on Server Fault and Unix & Linux: 

... but was not identified as a “New contributor” on the migrated question:


Ah, don’tcha love boilerplate text?  “The answers on that question” are not helpful because there are no answers on that question.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I brought this up a while ago with the older form.
